# Get all comments from modern Site pages in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages, list-comments, sharepoint-online-powershell

I have a requirement to fetch all the comments from all the site pages in a SharePoint Online site collection date wise. Is there a way to achieve it using Powershell?

I will be creating a timer job and running this query to send a notification to business users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST API to call the `/Comments` endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/GetItemById(x)/Comments
```

Here is the PowerShell code:

```
$SiteURL = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TargetSiteCollection"

Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

$ListName= "Site Pages"

$allSitePages = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName

foreach ($sitePage in $allSitePages)
{
    Write-host ------------------------------
    $pageID = $sitePage["ID"]
    Write-host 'Site Page' $pageID ':' $sitePage["Title"]
    $RestMethodURL = $SiteURL+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('$ListName')/GetItemById('$pageID')/Comments"
    $ListOfComments = Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod -Url $RestMethodURL
    if ($ListOfComments.value)
    {
        # Comments exsist!
        Write-host $ListOfComments.value.Count comments found:
        $ListOfComments.value
    } else {
        Write-host "No comments where found on this page."
    }
         
    Write-host ------------------------------ `n`n`n`n`n
}
```

Here is the PowerShell script output compared to the comments on the SharePoint page:
[image: PowerShell Output vs Comments on SharePint Page]

Comment: @Sivanrv, is this what you are looking for? Thanks!

Comment: Hi...thanks for your answer, but I'm facing issue in fetching all the comments using web api. Getting partial commments only

Comment: @Sivanrv, are you using the `Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod` and only getting partial comments?

Comment: even in web response I'm not getting if comments are more than 50. Ex: Comment count showing in page is 50 but in response I'm getting only around 35. Is replies not counted?, if so, can we include that in script by individual calls?

Comment: @Sivanrv, yes you're right. Unfortunately, replies to comments are not counted :(